# PHP exec_shell method return data limit?

Tags: php

I'm currently running a python script in using PHP's exec_shell method where said script prints out the data to do the transfer. I noticed that if the script prints out too much data (not certain how much) exec_shell will not return any of the data. I limited the scripts data set to find this result.

Is there a workaround for exec_shell's data limit so one can return infinite amounts of data with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `proc_open` or `popen` instead of `shell_exec` , and read chunks of data.

```
$chunk = 1024; 
if(($fp = popen($cmd, 'r')) !== false) {
    while(!feof($fp)) { 
        echo fread($fp, $chunk);
        flush();
    }
    pclose($fp);
}
```

If you're using this for a web application the ammount of data printed depends on the server configuration.  If you run your script on cli, it will print untill `feof`.